# URL for linksys WRT54GS firmware upgrade

Tags: router, updates, firmware

I am trying to "recover" from a bad firmware upgrade on my Linksys WRT54GS.  I can ping the router, and I can even get part of the web gui - but only parts of it - it's quite garbled.  I can go to `http://192.168.1.1/Upgrade.htm` (by typing in the address) & see some of the upgrade screen - I can even browse for and select the file, but there's no button to kick off the upgrade.

I'm hoping someone can provide me with a URL in which I can imbed the path to the file & kick off the upgrade, or even if someone has an idea on how to get the firmware flashed, that would be great - I've tried loading it with tftp as it's booting up.

Comment: Try using curl, wget, w3m or lynx to browse to the page. it removes all the css